# Can we add new picklist value in Approval Status?

Tags: approval-process

I want to add a new value in picklist field of Approval 'Status', if we add a comment on Approval then the Status should be "Approved with modifications". Please share you ideas on that.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't available to modify. An [approval process](http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/what_are_approvals.htm) has a very specific process it must adhere to in order to ensure that the process works. Here are some [other important considerations](https://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/approvals_considerations.htm) as well. There also isn't a standard way to capture if comments were entered or not.

If this is an absolute requirement, you could look into creating your own [approval process flow through Apex](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_process_example.htm). You would have to custom code the entire thing with a Visualforce component to handle the user's request for approval and input. The important part to note is:

```
Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest req2 = new Approval.ProcessWorkitemRequest();
req2.setComments('Approving request.');
req2.setAction('Approve');
req2.setNextApproverIds(new Id[] {UserInfo.getUserId()});
```

Now, instead of calling `.setComments();` with a static [String](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_apex250/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm) you can set an input field on the page and set the comments with that instead. It will then allow you to capture if comments have been made and update a Status field on the object to indicate the actual state. This will allow you to do a check like:

```
public String commentsField {get;set;}

if(commentsField.length() > 0){
    // update field to indicate modifications have occurred
}else{
    // update to normal approval
}
```